# Any clojurescript tutorials?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Are there already some good tutorial on ClojureScript? I would like to try it out, but don't know where to start exactly.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Fogus is writing [a series on ClojureScript](http://blog.fogus.me/tag/clj-compilation/) which you may find interesting.

- [Compiling Clojure to Javascript](http://blog.fogus.me/2011/07/21/compiling-clojure-to-javascript-pt1/) Jul 21, 2011
- [Compiling Clojure to JavaScript, pt. 2 – Why No Eval?](http://blog.fogus.me/2011/07/29/compiling-clojure-to-javascript-pt-2-why-no-eval/) Jul 29, 2011
- [Compiling Clojure to JavaScript, pt. 3 – The Himera Model](http://blog.fogus.me/2012/03/27/compiling-clojure-to-javascript-pt-3-the-himera-model/) Mar 27, 2012
- [The ClojureScript Compilation Pipeline](http://blog.fogus.me/2012/04/25/the-clojurescript-compilation-pipeline/) Apr 25, 2012

Comment: I'll update the answer when new parts of the series show up.

Comment: Part 2 and Part 3 seem pretty irrelevant to a newbie.  And sadly, there's no information on how to get up and running.  Is it ok to update this wiki with tutorials that are not from the Fogus series?

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at the newly released [ClojureScript One](http://clojurescriptone.com/) project. It is an example of a webapp written in ClojureScript and Clojure. Great piece of information describing the project can be found at their [wiki pages](https://github.com/brentonashworth/one/wiki).

Here's a screencast showing [ClojureScript REPL in action](http://vimeo.com/35153207).

Answer (score 9):

I've put up a first steps blog post/tutorial aimed at getting GUI elements working here: http://boss-level.com/?p=102 .  It also gives a brief intro to how to structure your project directory to interact with Clojurescript, as well as how to delve about within the Closure Library GUI elements.

Answer (score 8):

Not exactly tutorials but I found both Justin Grants Convex hull [demo](http://jng.imagine27.com/articles/2011-07-23-101007_clojurescript_demo_convex_hull.html) and the SVG graphing library [Apogee](https://github.com/liebke/apogee) helpful.

Answer (score 6):

You can find a gentle introduction to ClojureScript at https://github.com/magomimmo/modern-cljs

Comment: Thank you. I consider this to be the best resource for getting started.

Answer (score 2):

This is an older question, but I am gradually building up a library of sample code that I hope is helpful:

- Google Closure API examples: https://github.com/hhutch/cljs-closure-demos
- NodeJS examples: https://github.com/hhutch/clojurescript-nodejs-demos

Answer (score 2):

I am starting to make some demo videos of Clojurescript. I am a terrible presenter but I hope it helps:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lX6isnBn6mY

Answer (score 1):

Sierra and VanderHart's [*ClojureScript: Up and Running*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025139.do) is a good book.  One might feel that there's not enough content to justify the price, but sometimes good content is worth paying for, even when there's not a lot of it, if it's what you need.